# Can I target a specific element from another element hover in css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap `panel` and when I hover over it I want the `border` and `panel-heading`'s `background-color` to change.

I can get the `border` color to change but is there a way I can get the panel `background-color` to change too?

Is there some kind of nesting needed here?

```css
div.panel:hover {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  /*I want the panel-heading to be grey*/
}
.panel-default > .panel-heading {
  background-color: #16749F;
  color: #ddd;
}
.panel-default > .panel-heading:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you must `hover` the `panel` then target the child `panel-heading`

```css
.panel-default > .panel-heading {
  background-color: #16749F;
  color: #ddd;
}
.panel:hover > .panel-heading {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.panel-default:hover > .panel-heading {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

This means: If you hover `.panel-default`, the background-color of `.panel-heading` will change to grey.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and it is very easy.

CSS:

```
.panel:hover .panel-heading {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

This code changes panel heading border when you hover over your panel. Remember about CSS specificity and override Bootstrap's CSS properly.